# How can I generate specified number of integers in Linux?

Tags: bash

I found a lot of questions/answers related to this issue but I failed to choose what exactly what I need.

How can I generate specified number of integers?

```sh
#!/bin/sh
count=$1
# TODO: print $count integers to the console
```

which prints random integers one at a line.

```sh
$ generate.sh 32768
1
32
-47
9
-2
31
...
$
```

So that I can pipe the output to a file.

```sh
sh ./generate.sh 32768 > random_intengers.txt
```

I'm currently doing this.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
count=$1
for i in $(seq $count); do
    echo $SRANDOM
done
```

Is it good enough? Any other more efficient way using `od` or some?

Integer range is not a problem as long as not bigger than 32 bit, signed will be better

Comment: As this is a bash question your can use the built-in `for ((i=0; i<count; i++)); do` instead of calling the external `seq`. Note that "_Is it good enough?_" is opinion-based and opinion-based questions are discouraged on SO. Moreover, it strongly depends on what quality of randomness you need, something that you do not explain.

Comment: Can you use python ?

Comment: @balderman Yes I can, mate!

Comment: What should the script do - generate N random numbers in a range?

Comment: @balderman Any range is good unless exceeds 32-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `hexdump` and `/dev/urandom` if they are available:

```sh
$ count=5
$ hexdump -n $((4*count)) -e '/4 "%d\n"' /dev/urandom > random_integers.txt
$ cat random_integers.txt
535142754
455371601
-323071241
-1154116530
1841746137
```

Explanation:

- `-n $((4*count))` reads `4*count` bytes from `/dev/urandom`.
- `-e '/4 "%d\n"'` specifies a format string that uses 4 bytes at a time (`/4`) and prints them as an integer followed by a newline (`"%d\n"`).

Comment: Thank you. https://github.com/onacit/gist-java/blob/develop/src/test/resources/RandomIntegers.sh

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `jot` command available you could do this:

```
$ jot -r 10 0 1000
89
664
188
588
785
426
723
221
833
265
```

Prints `10` random (`-r`) numbers between `0` and `1000`. And it can also generate decimal numbers:

```
$ jot -r 10 0 1000.0
189.9
15.6
989.6
139.9
777.0
18.1
285.3
574.8
201.0
312.1
```

Or signed:

```
$ jot -r 10 -1000 1000.0
-551.5
-65.0
634.3
-814.6
881.2
-713.7
422.1
390.3
674.2
-750.9
```

Answer (score 1):

python based solution below

```
import sys
from random import randrange
count = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 1000

for x in range(0,count):
  print(randrange(100000))
```